# calling a shell command from python

Tags: python, shell, unix

I have an equivalent shell command(shown below) which I am trying to run "as-is" from a python script using call command on a linux box and running into compilation error,is there a better way other than call to runt this command?where am I going wrong?

```
from subprocess import call

def main ():

#ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit query --commit-message --files --current-patch-set status:open project:platform/vendor/company-proprietary/wlan branch:master |grep refs| awk -F ' ' {'print $2'} |tee refspecs.txt
    call (["ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit query", "--commit-message", "--files", "--current-patch-set", "status:open project:platform/vendor/company-proprietary/wlan branch:master","|grep refs| awk -F ' ' {'print $2'} |tee refspecs.txt")]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from subprocess import check_call

with open("refspecs.txt", "wb") as file:
    check_call("ssh -p 29418 company.com "
        "gerrit query --commit-message --files --current-patch-set "
        "status:open project:platform/vendor/company-proprietary/wlan branch:master |"
        "grep refs |"
        "awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'",
               shell=True,   # need shell due to the pipes
               stdout=file)  # redirect to a file
```

I've removed `tee` to suppress stdout.

Note: either part or even the whole command can be implemented in Python.

Comment: Isn't the `| grep | awk | tee` part easily replaceable with Python code? And I'm sure there's a package for SSH connections in Python. Why are you saying it can't be implemented in Python?

Comment: @jadkik94: He says "either part or even the whole command can be implemented in Python". I think you've read an extra "'t" that wasn't there.

Comment: @jadkik94: PS, there is no useful SSH in the standard library, but [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) is a very nice third-party one.

Comment: @abarnert Oh :) I even re-added that in your quote when reading, sorry about that :D

Comment: @Sebastian - I I use above code,I keep getting the error "ssh: Could not resolve hostname rcompany.comgerrit: Name or service not known"for some reason gerrit is getting appended to the hostname

Comment: @sebastian - got it..I missed a space after .com and  "

Comment: @sebastian - also how do I supress to stdout?currently the output is being printed on the console

Answer (score 2):

You need to split `"ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit query"` (do so manually, not using `.split()` etc.).

Right now your call to `subprocess.call()` tries to execute that whole string and you obviously have nothing with that name in your PATH.

Comment: You generally don't want to call `split` on a command-line string. If you already have separate arguments, it's obviously better to use a list (especially on POSIX, without `shell=True`), but if you have a string to start with, you're better off letting `subprocess` split it than trying to do it yourself. In particular, `str.split` doesn't understand quoting or escaping.

Comment: … or he could pass it as a string, instead of a list with 1 string in it (which is the only reason it's looking for the whole thing on the path). But yeah, passing it as a list of separate arguments is better.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're setting up a pretty serious pipeline the easiest thing to do would be to execute the command using the shell. Also, consider using [`check_call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) so you know if there was a problem. And of course the `)]` on the end should be `])` to fix the compilation error:

```
from subprocess import check_call

def main ():
    check_call("ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit query --commit-message --files --current-patch-set status:open project:platform/vendor/company-proprietary/wlan branch:master | grep refs | awk -F ' ' {'print $2'} | tee refspecs.txt", shell=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is all good advice… but it's not actually the reason the OP is getting a "compilation error".

Comment: It fixes the compilation error. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: note: you've changed the meaning of the command. The commands after the pipe are executed locally in the original bash command

Comment: @UNIXMAN - I keep getting the error "ssh: Could not resolve hostname rcompany.comgerrit: Name or service not known"for some reason gerrit is getting appended to the hostname

Comment: Make sure you have a space there and not some weird unicode non-breaking space character.

Answer (score 0):

You had the ) and ] in the wrong order to close the call.

```
call (["ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit query", "--commit-message", "--files", "--current-patch-set", "status:open project:platform/vendor/company-proprietary/wlan branch:master","|grep refs| awk -F ' ' {'print $2'} |tee refspecs.txt"])
```

Comment: Space-delimited shell arguments need to be different items in the list (e.g. `["ls", "-a"]`, not `["ls -a"]`. See @ThiefMaster's answer.

Comment: @David But that does seem to be OP's problem as it says "compilation error" which I believe means `SyntaxError`...

Comment: @David (assuming you're the downvoter): The OP wanted to know why his code was getting a "compilation error", and this answer tells him. It's true that the OP would then just get a _second_ error from within `subprocess`, and ThiefMaster explains that one, but that's not what the OP is asking. So, this one definitely doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: Yeah I don't know who is doing it, I didn't really look into fixing the actual command and instead I was just looking at the error the OP was receiving.

Comment: @ jadkik94 - how can the | grep | awk | tee part be easily replaceable with Python code?